# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate

Tags: node.js, reactjs, xcode, npm

I am new to work on react and recently started react application with npx create-react-app.
when I run npm start, the error is shown.

```
Starting the development server...

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate
  Referenced from: /Volumes/Untitled/MyProject/baseball/project/frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate
  Referenced from: /Volumes/Untitled/MyProject/baseball/project/frontend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release/fse.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/my_name/.npm/_logs/2020-07-29T10_15_47_695Z-debug.log
```

Any advice is appliciated.

VERSIONS:
node v12.18.2
npm v6.14.7
macOS: 10.15.6-x86_64
Xcode: 11.6

What I tried:

npm install after npm cache clean --force and  rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json in the directory

Comment: this may help you https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/313#issuecomment-609464785